# Dplyr table with p-value of kruskal wallis test

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with the mean of the variable (budget) over the groups (size and strictness) and the p-value of the Kruskall-Wallis test between budget and strictness (apart for every size group, so not comparing sizes here). I make the code separately and than combine everything in Excel as I do not know how to adjust the code to get is automatically. Every time I make a change in the data I have to make the table again. And also I have more variables for which I need to do this which takes up a lot of time.

I have the following code:

```
small2017 <- subset(total2017, size=="Small")
medium2017 <- subset(total2017, size=="Medium")
large2017 <- subset(total2017, size=="Large")

library(dplyr)

total2017 %>% group_by(size, strictness) %>%
summarise(mean=mean(budget, na.rm=TRUE), sd=sd(budget, na.rm=TRUE), n=n()) %>%
filter(!is.na(strictness))

Kruskal.test(budget ~ strictness, data=small2017)
Kruskal.test(budget ~ strictness, data=medium2017)
Kruskal.test(budget ~ strictness, data=large2017)
```

I made this in excel and copied it to latex.
[image]

You can find an example of my data below:

```r
example <- tibble::tribble(

     ~size,     ~budget, ~strictness,

   "Small", "11,718183",          1L,

  "Medium",  "5,264815",          2L,

   "Large",  "-0,43848",          NA,

   "Small",  "0,658158",          2L,

  "Medium",   "-1,2867",          3L,

   "Large",   "-0,8482",          2L,

   "Small",  "4,584138",          1L,

  "Medium",   "7,26868",          1L,

   "Large",   "-7,1868",          NA,

   "Small",  "8,186884",          1L,

  "Medium",   "16,1548",          NA,

   "Large",  "1,516844",          2L,

   "Small",   "-5,1687",          2L,

  "Medium",  "11,15687",          2L,

   "Large",   "-4,1867",          3L,

   "Small",   "7,25687",          3L,

  "Medium", "5,1682186",          1L,

   "Large", "-6,186515",          2L,

   "Small",    "7,2687",          3L

  )



head(example)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3

#>   size   budget    strictness

#>   <chr>  <chr>          <int>

#> 1 Small  11,718183          1

#> 2 Medium 5,264815           2

#> 3 Large  -0,43848          NA

#> 4 Small  0,658158           2

#> 5 Medium -1,2867            3

#> 6 Large  -0,8482            2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

As @dc37 pointed out your question is a little confusing.  A K-W test is appropriate when you have one dependent variable (budget) and one independent variable with more than two levels (for example size).  @dc37 has given you a great solution for that question.

If you want to compare budget against BOTH size and strictself you could change your dataframe to accomplish it but it would be the wrong test since you now have a non-parametric two-way ANOVA (budget ~ size * strictself).

If that's what you mean to do then a proper test is for example the Scheirer Ray Hare test which you can run from `rcompanion` as shown below.  Not sure where you got your example data from I turned the budget column into a `dbl` instead of a `chr`

```r
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527880
library(tibble)
library(rcompanion)

example <- tibble::tribble(
  ~size,     ~budget, ~strictself,
  "Small", 11718183,          1L,
  "Medium",  5264815,          2L,
  "Large",  -043848,          NA,
  "Small",  0658158,          2L,
  "Medium",   -12867,          3L,
  "Large",   -08482,          2L,
  "Small",  4584138,          1L,
  "Medium",   726868,          1L,
  "Large",   -71868,          NA,
  "Small",  8186884,          1L,
  "Medium",   161548,          NA,
  "Large",  1516844,          2L,
  "Small",   -51687,          2L,
  "Medium",  1115687,          2L,
  "Large",   -41867,          3L,
  "Small",   725687,          3L,
  "Medium", 51682186,          1L,
  "Large", -6186515,          2L,
  "Small",    72687,          3L
)

rcompanion::scheirerRayHare(budget ~ size * strictself, data = example)
#> 
#> DV:  budget 
#> Observations:  16 
#> D:  1 
#> MS total:  22.66667
#>                 Df  Sum Sq      H p.value
#> size             2  69.943 3.0857 0.21377
#> strictself       2 118.713 5.2373 0.07290
#> size:strictself  3  52.511 2.3166 0.50934
#> Residuals        8  98.833
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `broom` and `dplyr`, you can get perform the kruskall-wallis test for each group of strictself between size and budget and get the return of p.value for each:

```r
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

example %>% filter(!is.na(strictself)) %>% group_by(strictself) %>%
  do(tidy(kruskal.test(x = .$budget, g = .$size)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   strictself [3]
  strictself statistic p.value parameter method                      
       <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                       
1          1     0.333   0.564         1 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
2          2     3.75    0.153         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
3          3     2.70    0.259         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Partly, I want it seperately for each size class. So I think I can use subsets and than perform the test with the subdatasets.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide what would look like the expected outcome ? Just to be sure I understand what you are trying to test

Comment: Yes of course, sorry for the late reply. I also needed some time to figure out what I wanted exactly.

Comment: You don't actually have to make separate datasets.  You just need to modify @dc37 answer very slightly to get what you want leaving aside the validity of treating each size independently as though there was no chance of an interaction... I have added a new answer for you...

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to make separate datasets. You just need to modify @dc37 answer very slightly to get what you want leaving aside the validity of treating each size independently as though there was no chance of an interaction... I have added a new answer for you..

```r
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

example <- tibble::tribble(
  ~size,     ~budget, ~strictness,
  "Small", "11,718183",          1L,
  "Medium",  "5,264815",          2L,
  "Large",  "-0,43848",          NA,
  "Small",  "0,658158",          2L,
  "Medium",   "-1,2867",          3L,
  "Large",   "-0,8482",          2L,
  "Small",  "4,584138",          1L,
  "Medium",   "7,26868",          1L,
  "Large",   "-7,1868",          NA,
  "Small",  "8,186884",          1L,
  "Medium",   "16,1548",          NA,
  "Large",  "1,516844",          2L,
  "Small",   "-5,1687",          2L,
  "Medium",  "11,15687",          2L,
  "Large",   "-4,1867",          3L,
  "Small",   "7,25687",          3L,
  "Medium", "5,1682186",          1L,
  "Large", "-6,186515",          2L,
  "Small",    "7,2687",          3L
)

example$budget <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", example$budget))

head(example)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   size   budget strictness
#>   <chr>   <dbl>      <int>
#> 1 Small  11.7            1
#> 2 Medium  5.26           2
#> 3 Large  -0.438         NA
#> 4 Small   0.658          2
#> 5 Medium -1.29           3
#> 6 Large  -0.848          2

example %>%
  filter(!is.na(strictness)) %>%
  group_by(size, strictness) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(budget, na.rm=TRUE),
            sd=sd(budget, na.rm=TRUE),
            n=n())
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#> # Groups:   size [3]
#>   size   strictness  mean       sd     n
#>   <chr>       <int> <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#> 1 Large           2 -1.84  3.95        3
#> 2 Large           3 -4.19 NA           1
#> 3 Medium          1  6.22  1.49        2
#> 4 Medium          2  8.21  4.17        2
#> 5 Medium          3 -1.29 NA           1
#> 6 Small           1  8.16  3.57        3
#> 7 Small           2 -2.26  4.12        2
#> 8 Small           3  7.26  0.00837     2

example %>%
  filter(!is.na(strictness)) %>%
  group_by(size) %>%
  do(tidy(kruskal.test(x = .$budget,
                       g = .$strictness)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   size [3]
#>   size   statistic p.value parameter method                      
#>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                       
#> 1 Large      0.200   0.655         1 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 2 Medium     2.40    0.301         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 3 Small      3.93    0.140         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is already much better. Though the first code still gives the gruops below each other. Is there also a way to have the groups of strictness in the rows and the group sizes next to each other (as in my picture)?

Comment: Well now you're asking a whole different question about how to make fancy tables for display, so I suggest you repost.  You can twist the data anyway you like `example %>%
  filter(!is.na(strictness)) %>%
  group_by(size, strictness) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(budget, na.rm = TRUE),
            sd = sd(budget, na.rm = TRUE),
            n = n()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = size, values_from = c(mean, sd, n)) %>%
  arrange(strictness) %>% 
  select(strictness, mean_Small, sd_Small, n_Small)
`